How to freely rotate compound object with copy rotation constraint
I created a book that can be opened and closed. The rotation of the spine controls the opening and closing animation. The cover and the back of the book are children of the spine and the rotation of the spine is copied. This makes the book unfold or close.
The problem arises, when I want to rotate the entire book. This leads to an unwanted relative rotation of the cover and the back. Is there an easy fix or do I have to reconsider the setup?


You have to go to the end frame. The book is scaled up during animation.


You could parent all unparented objects to a higher root object like an empty, then rotate that. Or you could instance your model like I explain in this post and then just rotate that. Objects keep their animation even when instanced in GN.

I tried the first suggestion. It doesn't work. The issue remains. I add the file.

You can instance the animated objects from their own collection, like I refer to in this post, animate those in place in that collection, then animate the instanced object to get the rotation.

